# How to access folder packages in pubspec file?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

[image: How can I access all dependencies on folder packages?]

I have try in my pubspec.yaml , but it's working

```
packages:
   path: ../package1
```

Result

[image]

Comment: clearly mention your issue, or explain with code.what do you mean by folder packages?
custom package you made?

Comment: Yes, @ThusithaDeepal, the folder packages contain my own package I'm created

Comment: you may also like melos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it in the `dependency` part and specify a name.

```
dependencies:
  my_local_package:
    path: ../package1
```

And use it as

```
import 'package:my_local_package/package1.dart';
```

Comment: I still got an error https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZYYD.png

Answer (score 1):

you can use two ways,upload your package to github and access via it,or local..here are the code for it

Path dependency

A Flutter app can depend on a package using a file system path: dependency. The path can be either relative or absolute. Relative paths are evaluated relative to the directory containing pubspec.yaml. For example, to depend on a package, packageA, located in a directory next to the app, use the following syntax:

```
  dependencies:
  packageA:
    path: ../packageA/
```

from git

You can also depend on a package stored in a Git repository. If the package is located at the root of the repo, use the following syntax:

```
 dependencies:
    packageA:
      git:
        url: https://github.com/flutter/packageA.git
```

for more info get an idea from this https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages

Comment: I still got an error https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZYYD.png

Comment: it is relative the path in pubspec.yaml file,
 
/packages/your_package_folder,

according to image the "flutter native loading"

/packages/Flutter_Native_Loading

Comment: `flutter_native_loading:
    path: packages/flutter_native_loading`